# Jasny Bootstrap: can I specify File Input to accept only images?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jasny-bootstrap

I use Jasny Bootstrap for file input:
http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput

Is it possible to specify the input file type to accept only images? Like this:

```
<input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg" />
```

Comment: its solved. sorry
i just realized that jasny jas <input> tag there.
Thank you anw :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, since it's a standard attribute value for the [input](/questions/tagged/input) tag. Jasny doesn't change anything about that.

However, you should be aware that the [accept](/questions/tagged/accept) tag does not work in all browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept

Comment: thank you for the answer, but file input for jasny is :
`<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
  <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
  <div>
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="..."></span>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>`

**there's no <input> file tag anw.**

Comment: Ehm, there IS an input tag in the code you pasted :-), so you should be able to just use the code you posted in your question.
It's also in the example code on the Jasny website. See this screenshot: http://imgur.com/Z5bfgAQ